# folder lock 7.5 -- can't find the locked folder

Tags: windows, file-permissions, domain, folder-lock

I locked many important personal files with "folder lock 7.5" in a domain that i removed that domain now, but when I logged in as administrator I couldn't find the locked folder neither through application nor windows explorer (via command prompt).

But I know it's still there by checking the capacity of host folder.

Comment: Can you please provide me with more specific details? Also send me the relevant screenshots related to any error messages you might have received.

Comment: no, nothing is there to screen shot. I'm just checking the size of parent folder and it says some thing is here... but I cant see that something. it's not there and also it doesn't release the memory.no error! just cant see the folder.